# Stack Protection and Smashing using GCC

Tags: c, stack-smash

I am reading [Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit](http://phrack.org/issues/49/14.html#article) (in particular, this post refers to the "Buffer Overflows" section). The article is written for
a 32-bit machine however I am working on a 64-bit for which I take account in
my examples. One particular example is causing some issues that I cannot
explain. example3.c has the functionality of overwriting the return address to skip
an instruction in the main function. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int a, int b, int c)
{
  char buf1[5];
  char buf2[10];
  int *retptr;

  retptr = (void*)(buf2 + 40);
  (*retptr) += 8;
}

int main(void)
{
  int x;

  x = 0;
  function(1,2,3);
  x = 1;
  printf("%d\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

I compile this program with gcc v4.8.2 with the following command:

```
gcc example3.c -o example3
```

Note that by default the gcc compiler appears to implement some stack
protection such as address space layout randomisation and stack canaries. I have taken into account these safety measures in my calculation of the ret
pointer value. Here
is the corresponding assembly produced by
`gcc example3.c -S -fverbose-asm -o stack-protection.s`:

```
    .file   "example3.c"
# GNU C (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) version 4.8.2 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
#   compiled by GNU C version 4.8.2, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
# GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
# options passed:  -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu example3.c -mtune=generic
# -march=x86-64 -auxbase-strip verbose-stack-pro.s -fverbose-asm
# -fstack-protector -Wformat -Wformat-security
# options enabled:  -faggressive-loop-optimizations
# -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fauto-inc-dec -fbranch-count-reg -fcommon
# -fdelete-null-pointer-checks -fdwarf2-cfi-asm -fearly-inlining
# -feliminate-unused-debug-types -ffunction-cse -fgcse-lm -fgnu-runtime
# -fident -finline-atomics -fira-hoist-pressure -fira-share-save-slots
# -fira-share-spill-slots -fivopts -fkeep-static-consts
# -fleading-underscore -fmath-errno -fmerge-debug-strings
# -fmove-loop-invariants -fpeephole -fprefetch-loop-arrays
# -freg-struct-return -fsched-critical-path-heuristic
# -fsched-dep-count-heuristic -fsched-group-heuristic -fsched-interblock
# -fsched-last-insn-heuristic -fsched-rank-heuristic -fsched-spec
# -fsched-spec-insn-heuristic -fsched-stalled-insns-dep -fshow-column
# -fsigned-zeros -fsplit-ivs-in-unroller -fstack-protector
# -fstrict-volatile-bitfields -fsync-libcalls -ftrapping-math
# -ftree-coalesce-vars -ftree-cselim -ftree-forwprop -ftree-loop-if-convert
# -ftree-loop-im -ftree-loop-ivcanon -ftree-loop-optimize
# -ftree-parallelize-loops= -ftree-phiprop -ftree-pta -ftree-reassoc
# -ftree-scev-cprop -ftree-slp-vectorize -ftree-vect-loop-version
# -funit-at-a-time -funwind-tables -fverbose-asm -fzero-initialized-in-bss
# -m128bit-long-double -m64 -m80387 -maccumulate-outgoing-args
# -malign-stringops -mfancy-math-387 -mfp-ret-in-387 -mfxsr -mglibc
# -mieee-fp -mlong-double-80 -mmmx -mno-sse4 -mpush-args -mred-zone -msse
# -msse2 -mtls-direct-seg-refs

    .text
    .globl  function
    .type   function, @function
function:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $64, %rsp   #,
    movl    %edi, -52(%rbp) # a, a
    movl    %esi, -56(%rbp) # b, b
    movl    %edx, -60(%rbp) # c, c
    movq    %fs:40, %rax    #, tmp65
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)  # tmp65, D.2197
    xorl    %eax, %eax  # tmp65
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax #, tmp61
    addq    $40, %rax   #, tmp62
    movq    %rax, -40(%rbp) # tmp62, ret
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rax # ret, tmp63
    movl    (%rax), %eax    # *ret_1, D.2195
    leal    8(%rax), %edx   #, D.2195
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rax # ret, tmp64
    movl    %edx, (%rax)    # D.2195, *ret_1
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax  # D.2197, tmp66
    xorq    %fs:40, %rax    #, tmp66
    je  .L2 #,
    call    __stack_chk_fail    #
.L2:
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   function, .-function
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%d\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp   #,
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)    #, x
    movl    $3, %edx    #,
    movl    $2, %esi    #,
    movl    $1, %edi    #,
    call    function    #
    movl    $1, -4(%rbp)    #, x
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax  # x, tmp61
    movl    %eax, %esi  # tmp61,
    movl    $.LC0, %edi #,
    movl    $0, %eax    #,
    call    printf  #
    movl    $0, %eax    #, D.2200
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Executing example3 has the desired effect of skipping the second assignment to `x` and the program outputs `0`.

However, if instead I compile using the `-fno-stack-protector` option:

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector example3.c -S -fverbose-asm -o no-stack-protection.s
```

I receive the following assembly file:

```
    .file   "example3.c"
# GNU C (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) version 4.8.2 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
#   compiled by GNU C version 4.8.2, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
# GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
# options passed:  -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu example3.c -mtune=generic
# -march=x86-64 -auxbase-strip verbose-no-stack-pro.s -fno-stack-protector
# -fverbose-asm -Wformat -Wformat-security
# options enabled:  -faggressive-loop-optimizations
# -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fauto-inc-dec -fbranch-count-reg -fcommon
# -fdelete-null-pointer-checks -fdwarf2-cfi-asm -fearly-inlining
# -feliminate-unused-debug-types -ffunction-cse -fgcse-lm -fgnu-runtime
# -fident -finline-atomics -fira-hoist-pressure -fira-share-save-slots
# -fira-share-spill-slots -fivopts -fkeep-static-consts
# -fleading-underscore -fmath-errno -fmerge-debug-strings
# -fmove-loop-invariants -fpeephole -fprefetch-loop-arrays
# -freg-struct-return -fsched-critical-path-heuristic
# -fsched-dep-count-heuristic -fsched-group-heuristic -fsched-interblock
# -fsched-last-insn-heuristic -fsched-rank-heuristic -fsched-spec
# -fsched-spec-insn-heuristic -fsched-stalled-insns-dep -fshow-column
# -fsigned-zeros -fsplit-ivs-in-unroller -fstrict-volatile-bitfields
# -fsync-libcalls -ftrapping-math -ftree-coalesce-vars -ftree-cselim
# -ftree-forwprop -ftree-loop-if-convert -ftree-loop-im -ftree-loop-ivcanon
# -ftree-loop-optimize -ftree-parallelize-loops= -ftree-phiprop -ftree-pta
# -ftree-reassoc -ftree-scev-cprop -ftree-slp-vectorize
# -ftree-vect-loop-version -funit-at-a-time -funwind-tables -fverbose-asm
# -fzero-initialized-in-bss -m128bit-long-double -m64 -m80387
# -maccumulate-outgoing-args -malign-stringops -mfancy-math-387
# -mfp-ret-in-387 -mfxsr -mglibc -mieee-fp -mlong-double-80 -mmmx -mno-sse4
# -mpush-args -mred-zone -msse -msse2 -mtls-direct-seg-refs

    .text
    .globl  function
    .type   function, @function
function:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -36(%rbp) # a, a
    movl    %esi, -40(%rbp) # b, b
    movl    %edx, -44(%rbp) # c, c
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax #, tmp61
    addq    $40, %rax   #, tmp62
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)  # tmp62, ret
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax  # ret, tmp63
    movl    (%rax), %eax    # *ret_1, D.2195
    leal    8(%rax), %edx   #, D.2195
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax  # ret, tmp64
    movl    %edx, (%rax)    # D.2195, *ret_1
    popq    %rbp    #
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   function, .-function
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%d\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp   #,
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)    #, x
    movl    $3, %edx    #,
    movl    $2, %esi    #,
    movl    $1, %edi    #,
    call    function    #
    movl    $1, -4(%rbp)    #, x
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax  # x, tmp61
    movl    %eax, %esi  # tmp61,
    movl    $.LC0, %edi #,
    movl    $0, %eax    #,
    call    printf  #
    movl    $0, %eax    #, D.2196
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

and the corresponding executable does not produce the desired value of 0 but a
random value which I cannot reconcile with the assembly file.

My mental picture of the stack frame in the `-fno-stack-protector` case is (sfp = saved frame pointer, ret = return address):

```
low memory address     buf2 (16 bytes)  buf1 (8 bytes)  retptr (8 bytes)  sfp (8 bytes) ret       high memory address
<---                  [              ][              ][                ][             ][    ] ...
top of stack                                                                                      bottom of stack
```

My Question:

**Am I miscalculating the position of the return address in the unprotected case?**

Comment: Compile with `-S -fverbose-asm` and possibly also with `-O`

Comment: I have updated my question to include the output from `-fverbose-asm`. `-O` seems to obliterate the output such that the no stack protection version has no `function`. I cannot see from the additional comments the option places in the assembly file what is going wrong. The two versions both seem to be performing the same operations on the `retptr` variable.

Comment: The best bet to figure something like this out is to single step through the code so you can watch register/memory values.  It's been awhile since I did asm, but there's a sub qword instruction on the rsp register that doesn't exist in the non-protected version.

Comment: My guess would be that you are ignoring the variables that GCC adds to implement stack protection. One implementation shown here[1] uses extra local variables in a function, which disturbs the view of stack you have. [1][http://wiki.osdev.org/Stack_Smashing_Protector] Also, then you might say that you should see smashing in the `-fno-stack-protector` case not in the former one. Well, I think you have done some mistake in visualizing the stack in the former case, because I do not get the output i.e. `0` in the former case on ideone (http://ideone.com/dRVgZ2)

Comment: @Nishant Regarding stack protection, I have explicitly calculated for extra variables being added as can be seen in the stack-protection.s assembly file; the canaries are added before the buffers but it makes no difference to my calculation of the return address since the `retptr` in the protected case replaces the canary. I think ideone.com is inadmissible here; no matter what value you add to the buffer (to compute `retptr`) it compiles successfully and outputs `1`, when it should instead result in a memory violation, suggesting aggressive optimisation.

Comment: @incomplete Nice observation about ideone. Though if `retptr` replaces the canary in the protected case, then the program should exit after `function` returns instead of printing any output. Otherwise, you have to be sure that the canary value is the address of the instruction `x = 1` which seems unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I miscalculating the position of the return address in the unprotected case?

That part is correct, at least as long as the address fits in an int. The correct type for `retptr` would be `long` with x86-64 asm, so that the pointer can hold a 64 bit address.

You could double check that by running the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int a, int b, int c)
{
  char buf1[5];
  char buf2[10];
  int *retptr;

  retptr = (void*)(buf2 + 40);
  printf("retptr points to: %p\n", (long*)(long)*retptr);
  (*retptr) += 8;
}

int main(void)
{
  int x;


  printf("ret address is %p\n", &&label);
  x = 0;
  function(1,2,3);
label:
  x = 1;
  printf("%d\n", x);

  return 0;
}
```

By running this, you should be able to confirm that the address right after the `function` in is the one also held by `retptr`.

I believe that the reason you're not getting the expected `0`, lies in this line:

```
(*retptr) += 8;
```

On my 64 bit system, `x = 1` is compiled as:

```
  40058a:   c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
  400591:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  400594:   89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
```

The first line loads `1` in `x` and the two other lines pass the value of x as an argument to `printf()`. Notice how that's 7 bytes, and not 8. If you change the increment to 7, you should see `0`, as you expected.

Effectively, by adding 8, the `ret` instruction has setup the instruction pointer to point to `45`, rather than `8b`.
That code then becomes:

```
  45 fc                 rex.RB cld 
  89 c6                 mov    %eax,%esi
```

I'm not entirely sure what happens at that point, and I suspect that depends on the CPU model. Mine appears to skip the instructions until `mov %eax,%esi`, and so `printf` displays the value of whatever `%eax` was. If you look at the disassembly of `function()`, it turns out that `%rax` is used to store the value of `retptr`, and that's the seemingly random value that gets printed.

Comment: Ah, my bad for not using `long`. It appears that GCC allocates 8 bytes for the pointer anyway. I'm slightly confused about the instruction length being 7 bytes and why the 8-byte increment worked in the protected case. How do you obtain the layout of the instructions that implement `x = 1`? I used GDB's disassemble command but I don't get the same level detail as you show here. One point: "...the `ret` instruction has setup the instruction pointer to point to `45`, rather than `c7`", should that read `8b` instead of `c7`? Final question: How do you obtain the final assembly code snippet?

Comment: I've used `objdump -D` on the executable in order to get the disassembly. Regarding `c7` rather than `8b`, I did mean `c7`: when jumping to `c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00`, because of the extra byte added to the return address, we end up jumping to `45 fc 01 00 00...`. Regarding the final code snippet, I wrote a small program with: `char asm_snippet[]={0x45, 0xfc, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00 ...`. and then used `objdump -D`. You could also use `x /32i asm_snippet` in gdb. I learned this from here: https://lkml.org/lkml/2008/1/7/406

Comment: Isn't the idea that we want to jump passed the instruction `c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00`? So, adding 7 bytes would take us to `8b 45 fc` and adding an extra byte would cause us to jump passed `8b` to `45 fc`?